# What's the significance of "*" in setProperty?

Tags: java, jsp

Studying for a final and came across this in some code

```
<jsp:setProperty name="test" property="*" />
```

What's the significance of the *? What is it doing?

Comment: http://www.devmanuals.com/tutorials/java/jsp/setProperty.html

Comment: http://livedocs.adobe.com/jrun/4/Programmers_Guide/servletoptimizing3.htm. Look for `setProperty`.

Answer (score 0):

> This means in the matching Bean properties it will store all the
>   values in the request parameters. Name of the Bean properties must be
>   matched with the request parameters.

So given the bean:

```
package example;
public class Bean {

    private String test;

    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(String test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

}
```

And the JSP, `test2.jsp`:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="test.jsp" method="POST">
    <input name="test"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When the form is submitted and `test.jsp` is loaded, all matching parameters will be mapped to the bean properties:

**Test.JSP**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import = "example.Bean"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<jsp:useBean id="bean" class="example.Bean">
    <jsp:setProperty name="bean" property="*" />
</jsp:useBean>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
${bean.test }
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It *automatically* sets the bean property based on the request parameters that match. The * tells that the request coming in will bear the same name as a property in the bean.

This one:

```
<jsp:setProperty name="user" property="employeeId" param="*"/>
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
<jsp:setProperty name="user" property="employeeId" param="employeeId"/>
```

[image]

You cannot use the * if your scenario is like this:

[image]

For the case above, you need to manually do the mapping:

```
<jsp:setProperty name="user" property="employeeId" param="userId"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As one might expect, the asterisk indicates a wildcard; it's going to set every bean field that match(s) an incoming request parameter.  Usually, this is done using the [java.beans.Introspector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html) and [getPropertyDescriptors()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/BeanInfo.html#getPropertyDescriptors%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

**Some Examples:**

*Set all the values of comming request in to your bean*

```
<jsp:setProperty name="bean" property="*" />
```

*set value of the incoming request to specific property*

```
<jsp:setProperty name="bean" property="username" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Stores all of the values the user enters in the viewable JSP page (called request parameters) in matching bean properties. The names of the properties in the bean must match the names of the request parameters, which are usually the elements of an HTML form. A bean property is usually defined by a variable declaration with matching getter and setter methods (for more information, see http://java.sun.com/products/javabeans/docs/).